# Why does this pattern not match?

Tags: pattern-matching

Why does the following match?

```
MatchQ[HoldPattern[f], HoldPattern[_]]

True
```

But the following does not:

```
MatchQ[HoldPattern[f], HoldPattern[f]]

False
```

Or:

```
MatchQ[HoldPattern[f[1]], HoldPattern[f[_]]]

False
```

Comment: To match an expression itself is a pattern, you'll need `Verbatim` to "inactivate" pattern expression to make it match, something like `MatchQ[HoldPattern[f], Verbatim[HoldPattern[f]]]`.

Comment: Thank you, Verbatim[HoldPattern[f]] is the pattern that works, my unsuccessful  attempt was HoldPattern[HoldPattern].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first one matches because `HoldPattern` just prevents the pattern from evaluation, so it is equivalent to

```
MatchQ[HoldPattern[f], _]
(* True *)
```

The second one does not match because it is, again, equivalent to

```
MatchQ[HoldPattern[f], f]
(* False *)
```

What you are probably looking for is [`Verbatim`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Verbatim.html).

```
MatchQ[HoldPattern[f], Verbatim[HoldPattern[f]]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: I still don't understand. The job of HoldPattern is to extract the pattern of an expression without actually evaluating it, in that sense f == _ , f == f and f[1]==f[ _ ] .There is still something I am missing.

Comment: @EhabShoubaki, yes, but in the code, it is not `f` compared to `f`, but instead `HoldPattern[f]` compared to `f`, which is obviously not the same. `HoldPattern` in the first argument does not have any special meaning, it is just this exact expression.

Comment: This is good but I think the following variant might be preferrable. `In[82]:= MatchQ[HoldPattern[f], Verbatim[HoldPattern][f]]

Out[82]= True` It makes no difference in this example, but there can be cases where it is only the `HoldPattern` that should be verbatimmed (to make up a term).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, thanks for your valuable comment! Can you perhaps make a simple example so that I can include it in the answer?

Comment: @Domen , so the way to understand this is that MatchQ expects an "expression" in the first argument, and HoldPattern would still be the head of that expression, while for the second argument it expects a "pattern", which it extracts from inside the HoldPattern unevaluated and discards HoldPattern head. Verbatim forces MatchQ to keep that head.

Comment: The following shows how my usage differs from the usage in this post. I make no claim that one is better or worse than the other: which to use depends on the problem at hand. `In[93]:= MatchQ[HoldPattern[f_], Verbatim[HoldPattern][_]]

Out[93]= True

In[92]:= MatchQ[HoldPattern[f_], Verbatim[HoldPattern[_]]]

Out[92]= False` I guess I'm not sure which behavior was the ultimate goal, and maybe the method posted (and not my variant) is in fact what's wanted.